# Devilish and devious and etc

Tags: comparison

What are the differences between the similar adjectives:

> - Devilish
> - Devious
> - Satanic

For me they all mean the same, but once someone said:

> A person can be ‘devilish’ but not his/her behavior or actions. Actions are said to be ‘devious’. Meanwhile, "satanic" can be used for both.

Do you confirm his statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Devious* means *underhanded or sneaky*.

The dictionary definitions on Google are "showing a skillful use of underhanded tactics to achieve goals" and "(of a route or journey) longer and less direct than the most straightforward way".  I guess it makes sense that a person's actions would be devious, but you couldn't say a person him/herself is devious.  Though I would interpret *He is devious* to mean *He has a tendency to use devious methods to accomplish something*.

*Devilish* typically means *mischievous*.  This can be used light-heartedly, i.e. to describe someone playing a practical joke.

*-ish* is a suffix that means "to have the qualities of."  I see no reason why this can't apply to actions as well as people, places, or things.

> With a devilish swipe of her claws my cat showed me exactly how hungry she was.

*Satanic* means *of or worshipping Satan*.  Without significant context establishing otherwise it's a "serious" word that isn't equivalent to the above two at all.

---

> Bobby is devious.

I take this to mean I should be on my guard when dealing with Bobby just in case I'm a means to one of his underhanded schemes.

> Bobby is devilish.

I take this to mean Bobby is playful and probably the life of a good party.  I'll probably hang out with Bobby from time to time.

> Bobby is satanic.

I take this to mean Bobby is doing wicked things in his basement and I'm probably going to be scared of him.

Comment: Do your both's statements mean that "devilish guy" can mean exactly the same as "naughty guy"?

Comment: Do you confirm that depending on context, the adjective ‘devilish’ can imply a positive or a negative meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The most important distinction is that "devilish" and "satanic" are totally different levels of "bad".

As ultrasawblade says, "Devilish" means "mischievous". Someone pulling a practical joke might be "devilish". It can also be used to mean sexually playful or flirtatious.

"Satanic" can mean literally, "related to worship of Satan". As in, "The murders were committed by a satanic cult." Or figuratively it can mean "very evil".

You might say that someone putting a thumbtack on your chair was "devilish". You definitely would not say he was "satanic" -- or if you did, people would think you were way over-reacting. Likewise you might describe a brutal murder as "satanic". You would not say it was "devilish" -- or if you did, people would say you were way trivializing it.

I think all three words are routinely applied to both people and actions. "That was very devious, pretending to be the electrician to get in the building. You are a very devious person." "That was a devilish prank that Bob pulled. Bob is a very devilish person." "That murder was so brutal it was positively satanic. Only a satanic person would do something that horrible."

Interesting note on word origins: Just because "Satan" and "the Devil" are normally understood to be two names for the same being, that doesn't mean that "satanic" and "devilish" mean the same thing.